# Can someone tell me why these dropdowns don't get filled?

Tags: html, jquery

Can someone tell me these `Selects` don't get filled? I'm trying to write a Javascript program based on the alchemy mechanics in Skyrim.  The user selects two ingredients from a drop down menu.

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "alchemy.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <select id = "ing1">        
    </select>

    <select id = "ing2">    
    </select>
    
<button onClick = "mix()">Mix</button>
</body>
```

**EDIT**: I originally had shorter code to match the site's rules on brevity. Here is the entire JS file:

```
class Ingredient{
    //assign effects to item
    constructor(effect1, effect2, effect3, effect4){
        this.effect1 = effect1;
        this.effect2 = effect2;
        this.effect3 = effect3;
        this.effect4 = effect4;
    }
     //this may be easier understood with the second method read first

     //checks each of the effects of the second agent, to see if it matches
     //an effect in the first agent. 
    effectMatcher(otherAgentEffect)
    {
        switch(otherAgentEffect)
        {
            case this.effect1:
            alert("You created a " + this.effect1 + " potion!");
            break;
            case this.effect2:
            alert("You created a " + this.effect2 + " potion!");
            break;
            case this.effect3:
            alert("You created a " + this.effect3 + " potion!");
            break;
            case this.effect4:
            alert("You created a " + this.effect4 + " potion!");
            break;
        }
    }
    //takes a second Ingridient, checks each of its "effect" properties, runs them
    //through the 'x' method.
    mix(secondAgent)
    {
        this.effectMatcher(secondAgent.effect1);
        this.effectMatcher(secondAgent.effect2);
        this.effectMatcher(secondAgent.effect3);
        this.effectMatcher(secondAgent.effect4);
    }



}



const wheat = new Ingredient("restore health", "invisibility", "resist fire", "resist frost")
const torchbug_thorax = new Ingredient("damage health", "resist magic", "resist shock", "restore fatigue")
const frost_mirmain = new Ingredient("resist frost", "restore fatigue", "restore magicka", "resist fire")
const lavender = new Ingredient("fortify conjuration", "restore health", "restore fatigue", "restore magicka")
const dwemer_oil = new Ingredient("fortify one-handed", "damage health", "damage fatigue", "restore magicka")

let ingArray = ["wheat", "torchbug_thorax", "frost_mirmain", "lavender", "dwemer_oil"];


for (let i = 0; i < ingArray.length; i++) {
    console.log("for loop firing");
    console.log(ingArray[i]);
    //both these fire

    //this never fills, that's the problem
  $("#ing1").append("<option value = '" + i + "'>" + ingArray[i] + "</option>")
  $("#ing2").append("<option value = '" + i + "'>" + ingArray[i] + "</option>")
}



function mix()
{

//wheat.mix(frost_mirmain);
//this works, creates a resist from and resist fire potion

ingArray[parseInt(document.getElementById("ing1").value)].mix(ingArray[parseInt(document.getElementById("ing2").value)])
}
```

Comment: Is your javascript code _after_ the relevant HTML code? (i.e. close to the bottom of the HTML, before the closing `</body>` tag?) - Please include a [mre] for faster troubleshooting

Comment: I copied your code to a fiddle and it appears to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/f32b8w4a/

Comment: I posted the entirety of the JS code.  Does this help?

Comment: The full code also works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/v93bn40s/

Comment: Is class incredients located in alchemy.js file? If this is the case then you need to include that file after the elements you're using (best before closing `</body>`). Or use jQuery on Ready.